# When do Arrow and Flash cross over?

Tags: the-flash, continuity, arrow, arrowverse

I'm about to watch the last episode of season 2 of ***Arrow*** and I want to know when to start up on ***The Flash***, since they aired at the same time. *Arrow* is 2 seasons ahead of *The Flash*, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [already answered on the Sci-Fi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89101/31029) by [Mike Edenfield](http://stackexchange.com/users/187578/mike-edenfield). This is the start of his answer:

> Ideally, you should watch them in the order they aired. That is, if
>   you want to get the most coherent story from both shows, you should
>   watch Arrow up through the end of Season 2, then watch alternate
>   episodes of The Flash Season 1 and Arrow Season 3. There is only one
>   time when the shows seem to be significantly out of sync, and it won't
>   make a whole ton of difference. In particular, watching in this order
>   is the easiest way to guarantee not to spoil anything from either show
>   by watching the other.
>
> The second season of Arrow contains what is essentially a two-part
>   pilot episode for The Flash, where a mundane Barry Allen comes to
>   Starling City as a forensics expert; the end of that Arrow episode
>   sets up the first episode of The Flash.
>
> The first episodes of The Flash Season 1, and Arrow Season 3, take
>   place at the same time, and there are cross-over cameos at the end of
>   those episodes. About halfway through the season, there is a true
>   crossover, starting with The Flash and finishing in the following
>   day's Arrow.

But make sure to read the full answer, since it offers alternative viewing orders.

Comment: So, to simplify his answer, it would be best to do one episode of Flash then one episode of Arrow?

Comment: That answers out of date.

Comment: @cde Did they change the contents of the previously aired episodes?

Comment: @CodyHarness more crossovers

Comment: @cde Yes, in the next seasons. But this was about the first season of Flash.